# Error in uploading file on S3 when bucket name containing periods(dots) through c# SDK

Tags: c#, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have created two bucket on S3, named like "demobucket" and "demo.bucket". 
When I am uploading any file on "demobucket" it works fine. But when I upload file on "demo.bucket", it gives me an error "Maximum number of retry attempts reached : 3"

My concern is that what is the problem in uploading file when bucket name contain periods(dots).

My code is:

```
public static bool UploadResumeFileToS3(string uploadAsFileName, Stream ImageStream, S3CannedACL filePermission, S3StorageClass storageType)
    {
        try
        {
            AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY);

PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.WithKey(uploadAsFileName);
            request.WithInputStream(ImageStream);
            request.WithBucketName("demo.bucket");
            request.CannedACL = filePermission;
            request.StorageClass = storageType;

            client.PutObject(request);
            client.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I would add the Bucket name as a parameter to your method and re-run. Those 2 buckets are under the same account , with same setting  ?

Comment: @Mzf: Is there any difference if I pass bucket name as parameter and static like I did. And those 2 buckets are under the same account and same region.

Comment: Well, from my experience there is no problem using periods in bucket name.

Comment: What version of the AWS SDK for .NET are you using?

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko: It's version 1.3

Comment: @NamanGoyal, the latest version is 1.5.20. Can you try it with that version?

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko: I have tried with the latest version 1.5.20. But still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem establishing a secure connection to S3 when the bucket name contains a period. The issue is explained well here: http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html.

One solution is to create your S3 client passing a third argument which causes it to use HTTP instead of HTTPS. See [Amazon S3 C# SDK "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568288/amazon-s3-c-sharp-sdk-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-could-not-establish).

```
    AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
    {
        ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
        CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP,
        RegionEndpoint = region
    };
```

However, be aware that this is not secure and Amazon does not recommend it. Your secret access key could possibly be intercepted. I have not yet found a secure way to upload a file to a bucket with a period in the name.

If you are using a recent version of AWSSDK.dll (at least 2.0.13.0), you can do this instead:

```
    AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
    {
        ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
        ForcePathStyle = true,
        RegionEndpoint = region
    };
```

This forces the S3Client to use the version of the path to your bucket which avoids the problem.